# Discord Bot does not show activity status

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

My Discord bot does not show the activity status I have tried several methods but none worked my current code looks like this.

```
client.once('ready', () => {
  try {
    client.user.setActivity('Test', { type: 'PLAYING' });
    console.log(`Bot's Status: successfully updated`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Bot's Status: error while updating status`, error);
  }
});
```

I am using node.js v18.18.1
and discord.js the latest version

I have already tried with `.setPresence` see below but it did not work either.

```
client.once('ready', async () => {
  try {
    client.user.setPresence({
      status: 'online',
      activity: {
        name: 'Test',
        type: 'PLAYING'
      }
    });
    console.log(`Bot's Status: successfully updated`)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Bot's Status: error while updating status`)
  }
});
```

So either I'm not awake enough or it just doesn't work the bot has got adminesstrator rights has already been kicked and reloaded and the token has been reset but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the latest version of `discord.js` then the examples you showed are no longer valid (they used to work before like 2 major versions behind).

Right now, for you to change the presence, you should:

```js
import { ActivityType } from 'discord.js'; // Top of the file

client.user.setPresence(
  activities: [{ name: 'Test', type: ActivityType.Playing }],
  status: 'online'
);
```

For more info, check out the [setPresence()](https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/discord.js/main/ClientUser:Class#setPresence) method's documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much i didn't now that was a thing have a wonderful day <3

Answer (score 0):

"type: 'PLAYING'" is no longer available in discord.js v14 you would need to use the number values or ActivityType Enums

```
const {ActivityType} = require("discord.js");

await client.user.setPresence({
        activities: [{ name: `Test`, type: ActivityType.Playing}],
        status: "online",
    });
```